# jquery datepicker beforeShowDay works for wrong month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I'm using jquery's datepicker to select dates and I want to highlight some dates - but I'm experiencing a strange problem with **beforeShowDay**.

When the page loads it seems that the json data is loaded, but when I click into the input box and datepicker appears, nothing is highlighted. After I click on forward month or backward, data from a previous month is loaded (e.g. click in input -> datepicker appears -> no highlights -> click on next month -> data from prev month appears highlighted)...

I've googled a long time now, checked if data is loaded before everything, but somehow this behaviour is not changing. Both datepicker experience the same problem.

(jquery-ui datepicker 1.10.1, jquery 1.9.1)

I'm glad about every hint!

```
var resDates;
var done = false;

function markDate(date) {
    var ret = [true, 'free'];

    if (!done) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "modules/OutShop/getReservations.php",
            data: {item_id: $("#item-id").val()},
            async: false,
            success: function (dates) {
                resDates = dates;
                done = true;
            }
        });
    }


    $.each(resDates, function(key, value) {
        var d = (date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + date.getMonth()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));
        if (d == value["day"]) {
        //$("body").append("d: " + d + ", v: " + value["day"] + ", s: " + value["status"] + "  ");
        //$("body").append("s: " + value["status"] + "  ");
            if (value["status"] == "1")
                ret = [false, 'marked'];
            else if (value["status"] == "2")
                ret = [false, 'reserved'];
            else
                ret = [true, 'free'];
        }
    });

    return ret;
}

$(document).ready(function() {


    if (!done) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "modules/OutShop/getReservations.php",
            data: {item_id: $("#item-id").val()},
            async: false,
            success: function (dates) {
                resDates = dates;
                //done = true;
            }
        });
    }

    $("#item-datepicker-min").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        defaultDate: +3,
        minDate: +3,
        beforeShowDay: markDate,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#item-datepicker-max").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $("#item-datepicker-max").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: +3,
        defaultDate: +6,
        beforeShowDay: markDate,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#item-datepicker-min").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
For further information: This is an example json object I got from the ajax response.

> [{"status":3,"day":"2013-04-10"},{"status":3,"day":"2013-04-11"},{"status":3,"day":"2013-04-12"},{"status":3,"day":"2013-04-13"},{"status":2,"day":"2013-04-10"},{"status":2,"day":"2013-04-11"},{"status":2,"day":"2013-04-12"},{"status":2,"day":"2013-04-13"}]

Comment: so are you saying that it works ok for all months EXCEPT the one that is displayed initially? Can you post the contents of resDates (or a sample of it)

Comment: Not really. It displays nothing on init, and then - after switching a month - classes are e.g. added for the dates in april when I'm in may. By the way - the php script just outputs every date, so there is no way that it delivers data for a wrong month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your months are offset by 1, the javascript method date.getMonth() returns the months zero-based (eg. January is 0, Feb is 1) and your PHP script returns the date in normal format (Jan is 1, Feb is 2)

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

So if you change

```
var d = (date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + date.getMonth()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

to

```
var d = (date.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + date.getMonth()+1).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

you should get the right month showing